# How do I exclude entered values in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

For example the array has a lenth of 10. All values inputed that is *lesser than 5* and *greater than 10* will not be counted and will also not be added. Instead, I would like the program to collect 10 inputed values that is not *lesser than 5* and not *greater than 10*. It doesnt matter how many input I can get as long as I can have 10 values that matches the condition.  Please help me since I'm a beginner when it comes to coding. Thank you very much :)

```
    int index;
    int sum = 0;

    System.out.print("Number of index: ");
    index = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
    int [] num = new int[index];
    int max = num[0], min = 32768;

    //input
    for(int x = 0; x < num.length; x++) {
        System.out.print("Enter Number: ");
        num[x] = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
    }

    //sum
    for(int y = 0; y< num.length; y++) {
         sum += num[y];
    }

    for(int z = 0; z < num.length; z++) {
        //max
        if (num[z]>max) {
            max =num[z];
        }
        //min
        if (num[z]< min) {
            min = num[z];
        }
    }

    System.out.println("The max number is "+max);
    System.out.println("The min number is "+min);
    System.out.println("The sum is "+sum);
```

Comment: Tho I was able to find the minimum and maximum value, same as with the sum of all inputed values.

Answer (score 1):

First you should note that JavaScript and Java are two different languages

You have to use the `while(arr.length < 10)` and put the logic inside it.

```
int[] arr = [10];
int index =  0;
while(index < 10) {
  int input = Integer.parseInt(System.in.readLine())

  if(input >= 5 && input <= 10) arr[index++] = input;
}
```

Note that I have not tested the code, since I don't have installed, but am sure you will get the point.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your java code to the following Js code.

**Your Code**

```
System.out.println("The max number is "+max);
System.out.println("The min number is "+min);
System.out.println("The sum is "+sum);
```

**Replace Code**

```
<p id="max"></p>
<p id="min"></p>
<p id="sum"></p>  
<script>
document.getElementById("max").innerHTML = max;
document.getElementById("min").innerHTML = min; 
document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = sum;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write this code that will specifically solve your mentioned problem.

```
int n;
int num=new int[10];
for(int i=0;i<num.length;i++)
{
    System.out.print("Enter Number: ");
    n=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

    if(n>=5 && n<=10)
    {   num[i]=n;}

    else if(i>0)
    {   i--;}
}
```